# Gulp copy directory over and files

Tags: gulp

I have a directory setup like this:

- node_modules
- src

  - index.js

I'm trying to copy these to a dist folder like this:

- node_modules
- index.js

I've tried a number of variations, such as

`gulp.src(['src/**/*', 'node_modules/**']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));`

But this places all of the node_modules in the /dist and not within the node_modules directory.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `gulp.src` that the base directory for `node_modules/**` is `.` so that the `node_modules` created at the destination. However, you cannot set the base to `.` for `src/**/*` because that would mean that the `src` directory would be created in your destination. So you need in effect to specify two sets of sources. [`gulp-add-src`](https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src) can help with this.

Something like this should work:

```
var addsrc = require("gulp-add-src");

gulp.src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(addsrc('node_modules/**', { base: '.'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```